# Pygame Opening window and crashing immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, crash

I coded this game in sublime and it is working fine when I run it in the same editor. But when I  run it directly using Python/Python3.8, The window opens and then immediately closes by itself. I also tried to convert it into an executable using cx_Freeze but while running the .exe file, again the window opened for a second and then closed by itself. Please help!

PS: Errors start coming only after I jump

EDIT - The errors went away after I downgraded to python 3.7.7 and installed pygame 2.0.0dev6, But when I open it directly with python, It still crashes immediately.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600,390))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('dungeon.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bulletSound=pygame.mixer.Sound('bullet.wav')
hitSound=pygame.mixer.Sound('hit.wav')
music=pygame.mixer.Sound('music.wav')
music.set_volume(0.3)
music.play(-1)

class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox=(self.x+20,self.y+12,24,50)
        self.alive=True

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount== 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if not(self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount +=1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox=(self.x+20,self.y+12,24,50)
        #pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),self.hitbox,2)

    def hit(self):
        self.alive=False
        Font=pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',100,True)
        Font2=pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',40)
        text2=Font2.render('Press Enter to restart', 1 , (255,0,0))
        text=Font.render('GAME OVER', 1, (255,255,255))
        win.blit(text,(250-(text.get_width()/2),100))
        win.blit(text2,(250-(text.get_width()/2),200))
        pygame.display.update()
        while not self.alive:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                restart()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    dead=False
                    pygame.quit()



class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color,facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self,win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)

class enemy(object):
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'), pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'), pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'), pygame.image.load('R9E.png'), pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'), pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'), pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png'), pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,end):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.end=end
        self.path=[0,self.end]
        self.walkCount=0
        self.vel=3 
        self.hitbox=(self.x+17,self.y+2,28,57)
        self.hitNumber=0
        self.levelupScore = 10

    def draw(self,win):
        self.move()
        if self.walkCount==33:
            self.walkCount=0
        if self.vel > 0:
            win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount//3],(self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
             win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount//3],(self.x,self.y))
             self.walkCount += 1
        if self.vel > 0:
            self.hitbox=(self.x+15,self.y+2,25,57)
        else:
            self.hitbox=(self.x+25,self.y+2,25,57)

        #pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),self.hitbox,2)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel>0:
            if (self.x+self.vel)<self.path[1]:
                self.x+=self.vel
            else:
                self.vel=self.vel * -1
                self.walkcount=0
        else:
            if self.x-self.vel>self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel=self.vel * -1
                self.walkcount=0

    def hit(self):
        self.hitNumber+=1
        if self.hitNumber==self.levelupScore:
            self.levelupScore += 10
            if self.vel > 0:   
                self.vel += 2
            else:
                self.vel -= 2   

def start():
    global run
    start=True
    while start:
        clock.tick(27)
        win.blit(bg,(0,0))
        font=pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',80)
        text=font.render('Goblin Dungeon', 1, (255,255,255))
        win.blit(text,(100,20))
        font2=pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',40)
        text2=font2.render('Press Enter to start', 1, (255,0,0))  
        win.blit(text2,(200,350)) 
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                start = False
                break
                pygame.quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
            run=True
            return

def redrawGameWindow():
    score=goblin.hitNumber + goblin2.hitNumber
    Font=pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',30,True)
    text=Font.render("Score: "+ str(score),1,(255,255,255))
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    win.blit(text,(450,10))
    man.draw(win)
    goblin.draw(win)
    goblin2.draw(win)

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()

def restart():
    man.alive = True
    man.x = 250
    goblin.x, goblin.vel, goblin.hitNumber = 0, 3 , 0
    goblin2.x, goblin2.vel, goblin2.hitNumber = 400, 3, 0



#mainloop
man = player(250, 230, 64,64)
goblin=enemy(0,230,64,64,550)
goblin2=enemy(400,230,64,64,550)
shootDelay=0
bullets = []
run = False
start()
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            break

    if man.hitbox[1]<goblin.hitbox[1]+goblin.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3]>goblin.hitbox[1]:
        if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin.hitbox[0] + goblin.hitbox[2]:
            man.hit()

    if man.hitbox[1]<goblin2.hitbox[1]+goblin2.hitbox[3] and man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3]>goblin2.hitbox[1]:
        if man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > goblin2.hitbox[0] and man.hitbox[0] < goblin2.hitbox[0] + goblin2.hitbox[2]:
            man.hit()

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.y-bullet.radius>=goblin.hitbox[1] and bullet.y+bullet.radius<goblin.hitbox[1]+goblin.hitbox[3]:
            if bullet.x+bullet.radius>goblin.hitbox[0] and bullet.x-bullet.radius<goblin.hitbox[0]+goblin.hitbox[2]:
                goblin.hit()
                hitSound.play()
                bullets.remove(bullet)
                print("Goblin1- ",goblin.hitNumber, "vel = ", goblin.vel)


            elif bullet.y-bullet.radius>=goblin2.hitbox[1] and bullet.y+bullet.radius<goblin2.hitbox[1]+goblin2.hitbox[3]:
                if bullet.x+bullet.radius>goblin2.hitbox[0] and bullet.x-bullet.radius<goblin2.hitbox[0]+goblin2.hitbox[2]:
                    goblin2.hit()
                    hitSound.play()
                    bullets.remove(bullet)
                    print("Goblin2- ",goblin2.hitNumber, " vel = ", goblin2.vel)

        if bullet.x < 600 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if man.alive:
        if shootDelay>0:
            shootDelay+=1
        if shootDelay==5:
            shootDelay=0

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootDelay==0:
            bulletSound.play()

            if man.left:
                facing = -1
            else:
                facing = 1

            if len(bullets) < 5:
                bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height//2), 5, (0,0,255), facing))
                shootDelay+=1

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
            man.x -= man.vel
            man.left = True
            man.right = False
            man.standing = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 620 - man.width - man.vel:
            man.x += man.vel
            man.right = True
            man.left = False
            man.standing = False
        else:
            man.standing = True
            man.walkCount = 0

        if not(man.isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                man.isJump = True

                man.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if man.jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if man.jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.3 * neg
                man.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                man.isJump = False
                man.jumpCount = 10
    if not man.alive:
        man.standing=True


    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

And these were the errors that I got in IDLE even though the game runs flawlessly

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 43
    win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 52
    win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 46
    win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 50
    win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 209, in <module>
    man.hit()
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 67, in hit
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open it in the IDLE that comes with python(shell)? Right click on your .py file choose edit with IDLE. The IDLE comes up, and then press F5 to run your code. It should write your error on the console.

EDIT:
Seeing your error log, its probably because you use python 3.8, try it with 3.7 or older

Comment: Yes I just did that and Have attached the error in the ending of my question.

Comment: Tried running it with python 3.7 and got the following error                               ```"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manuv\Documents\Python Scripts\Goblin Dungeon\Goblin Dungeon.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'"```

Comment: Install pygame with pip for python 3.7 too, and when you try to run your game make sure that you launched it with python 3.7 not 3.8. When I tried 3.8 I had a lot of issues too because a lot of modules are not yet compatible with it, so I recommend to stick to 3.7 for a while. If you decide to use 3.7 from now on, you should uninstall 3.8.

Comment: Okay will try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there are compatibility issues with pygame 1.96 and python 3.8. Try updating to 2.0.0.dev6:

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Don't forget to run cmd or powershell as administrator

Comment: Just tried, Same errors in IDLE and still closes after opening when opening with python.

Comment: @ManuvikashSaravanakumar I've copied your code, disabled sound and loaded random pictures, everything works fine with python 3.7.7 and pygame 2.0.0.dev6. Does not crash at any command. Maybe try using `.convert()` on loading images. I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Okay will try ! Thanks

Comment: Installed python 3.7.7 and pygame 2.0.0dev6, works without errors in IDLE but still closes immediately when opening directly with python.

Comment: Well, glad that you got somewhere. By directly with python I assume you mean from cmd with python main.py command? Do you have multiple versions of python installed? And if you do have you specified which one do you want to use?

Comment: The window says pygame.error: couldn't load 'R1.png' before crashing

Comment: Ok, this definitely has to do with locating the path to the image. Make sure they are in the same folder as the file.py. Alternatively try using absolute paths, but note that this is not a good practice, so do this just for testing and always try to use relative paths wherever is possible.